# Extracting e-mail address from several websites

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have the below code, it retrieves e-mail addresses from one website only. I'd like it to work for several websites.

It searches the website's source code for the @ character and pastes it on a range of the sheet.

Is there any way I could get these from all websites of a list and place them one below the other on the sheet?

```vb
Private Sub Email_Extractor_From_Website()
    Dim oWebData As Object, sPageHTML  As String, sWebURL As String
 
    'The code works fine for 1 website of the below, however i'd like it to work for several websites
    sWebURL = "http://www.example1.com/"
    sWebURL = "http://www.example2.com/"
    sWebURL = "http://www.example3.com./"
    'etc
    'Extract data from website to Excel using VBA
    Set oWebData = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    oWebData.Open "GET", sWebURL, False
    oWebData.send
    sPageHTML = oWebData.responseText
 
    'Get webpage data into Excel
    Extract_Email_Address_From_Text sPageHTML
End Sub

Private Sub Extract_Email_Address_From_Text(Optional Text_Content As String)
    Dlim_List = " ""(),:;<>@[\]"
    
    'Get Text Content and assign to a Variable
    If Text_Content = "" Then
        Text_Content = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1)
    End If
    Web_Page_Text1 = Text_Content
    If Web_Page_Text1 = "" Then
        MsgBox "Error: No Input Provided - Provide Input"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Scan each word in Text and Extract Email Addresses
    ORow = 2
    While (Web_Page_Text1 <> "")
    
        'Locate position of symbol "@"
        First_@ = VBA.InStr(1, Web_Page_Text1, "@", vbTextCompare)
        
        'If there is no occurance of "@" then terminate process
        If First_@ = 0 Then GoTo End_sub:
        
        'Seperate
        Web_Page_Text2 = VBA.Mid(Web_Page_Text1, 1, First_@ - 1)
        Web_Page_Text3 = VBA.Mid(Web_Page_Text1, First_@ + 1)
        Dlim_Pos_Max = 99999
        Dlim_Pos_Min = 0
        
        For i = 1 To VBA.Len(Dlim_List)
            Dlim_2_Compare = VBA.Mid(Dlim_List, i, 1)
                        
            Dlim_Pos = VBA.InStrRev(Web_Page_Text2, Dlim_2_Compare, -1, vbTextCompare)
            If (Dlim_Pos > Dlim_Pos_Min) And (Dlim_Pos > 0) Then Dlim_Pos_Min = Dlim_Pos
    
            Dlim_Pos = VBA.InStr(1, Web_Page_Text3, Dlim_2_Compare, vbTextCompare)
            If (Dlim_Pos < Dlim_Pos_Max) And (Dlim_Pos > 0) Then Dlim_Pos_Max = Dlim_Pos
        Next i
        If Dlim_Pos_Max = 0 Then GoTo End_sub:
        
        'get Email list to Text Variable
        Email_Domain_Part = VBA.Mid(Web_Page_Text3, 1, Dlim_Pos_Max - 1)
        Email_Local_Part = VBA.Mid(Web_Page_Text2, Dlim_Pos_Min + 1, VBA.Len(Web_Page_Text2) - Dlim_Pos_Min)
        Mail_Address = Email_Local_Part & "@" & Email_Domain_Part
        
        'Scan through remaining content
        ORow = ORow + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(ORow, 2).Select
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(ORow, 2) = Mail_Address
        Web_Page_Text1 = VBA.Mid(Web_Page_Text1, Dlim_Pos_Max + First_@ + 1)
    Wend
End_sub:
    MsgBox " Process Completed"
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code it is working fine for one url. For more than one, you need to write another function which will takes url and column number as arguments. You only said it is not work but do you got any error or pls elaborate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code and modified little bit. If it works, then change the below function name:

```
Sub Test()
 Email_Extractor_From_Website "www.yahoo.com", 2
 Email_Extractor_From_Website "www.yahoo.com", 3
End Sub

Private Sub Email_Extractor_From_Website(sWebURL As String, OCol As Integer)
Dim oWebData As Object, sPageHTML  As String

'The code works fine for 1 website of the below, however i'd like it to work for several websites
'etc
'Extract data from website to Excel using VBA
 Set oWebData = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
 oWebData.Open "GET", sWebURL, False
 oWebData.send
 sPageHTML = oWebData.responseText

'Get webpage data into Excel
 Extract_Email_Address_From_Text sPageHTML, OCol
End Sub


Private Sub Extract_Email_Address_From_Text(Text_Content As String, OCol As Integer)
Dlim_List = " ""(),:;<>@[\]"

'Get Text Content and assign to a Variable
If Text_Content = "" Then
   Text_Content = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1)
End If
Web_Page_Text1 = Text_Content
If Web_Page_Text1 = "" Then
   MsgBox "Error: No Input Provided - Provide Input"
  Exit Sub
End If

'Scan each word in Text and Extract Email Addresses
ORow = 2
While (Web_Page_Text1 <> "")

'Locate position of symbol "@"
First_@ = VBA.InStr(1, Web_Page_Text1, "@", vbTextCompare)

'If there is no occurance of "@" then terminate process
If First_@ = 0 Then GoTo End_sub:

'Seperate
Web_Page_Text2 = VBA.Mid(Web_Page_Text1, 1, First_@ - 1)
Web_Page_Text3 = VBA.Mid(Web_Page_Text1, First_@ + 1)
Dlim_Pos_Max = 99999
Dlim_Pos_Min = 0

For i = 1 To VBA.Len(Dlim_List)
    Dlim_2_Compare = VBA.Mid(Dlim_List, i, 1)

    Dlim_Pos = VBA.InStrRev(Web_Page_Text2, Dlim_2_Compare, -1, vbTextCompare)
    If (Dlim_Pos > Dlim_Pos_Min) And (Dlim_Pos > 0) Then Dlim_Pos_Min = Dlim_Pos

    Dlim_Pos = VBA.InStr(1, Web_Page_Text3, Dlim_2_Compare, vbTextCompare)
    If (Dlim_Pos < Dlim_Pos_Max) And (Dlim_Pos > 0) Then Dlim_Pos_Max = Dlim_Pos
Next i
If Dlim_Pos_Max = 0 Then GoTo End_sub:

'get Email list to Text Variable
Email_Domain_Part = VBA.Mid(Web_Page_Text3, 1, Dlim_Pos_Max - 1)
Email_Local_Part = VBA.Mid(Web_Page_Text2, Dlim_Pos_Min + 1, VBA.Len(Web_Page_Text2) - Dlim_Pos_Min)
Mail_Address = Email_Local_Part & "@" & Email_Domain_Part

'Scan through remaining content
ORow = ORow + 1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(ORow, OCol).Select
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(ORow, OCol) = Mail_Address
Web_Page_Text1 = VBA.Mid(Web_Page_Text1, Dlim_Pos_Max + First_@ + 1)
Wend
End_sub:
MsgBox " Process Completed"

End Sub
```

Comment: That's great! It works perfectly. Just a question: Is it possible to take out the Message Box so it doesn't "stuck" as it finishes retrieving the mails from one website? Thanks!

Comment: Just comment it.. Put a single quote in the start of the Msgbox line.